# why is this pine script no longer working?

Tags: pine-script

This pine script stopped working about 2 weeks ago or longer. I assume its when the language was upgraded to V4 or something along those lines. The code is below.

```
exch = input(0, type = integer, minval=0, maxval=8,
    title="Exch: NYSE=0 NASDAQ=1 AMEX=2 OTC=3 TSX=4 TSXV=5 ETFS=6 Total=7 CAD Total=8")
adv_ticker = 
    exch == 8 ? "AVVX" : 
    exch == 7 ? "AVVT" : 
    exch == 6 ? "AVVE" : 
    exch == 5 ? "AVVV" : 
    exch == 4 ? "AVVS" : 
    exch == 3 ? "AVVD" : 
    exch == 2 ? "AVLU" : 
    exch == 1 ? "AVVQ" : 
    "AVVN"
dec_ticker = 
    exch == 8 ? "DVCX" : 
    exch == 7 ? "DVCT" : 
    exch == 6 ? "DVCE" : 
    exch == 5 ? "DVCV" : 
    exch == 4 ? "DVCS" : 
    exch == 3 ? "DVCD" : 
    exch == 2 ? "DVCA" : 
    exch == 1 ? "DVCQ" : 
    "DVCN"  
adv1 = security(adv_ticker, period, close)
dec = security(dec_ticker, period, close)
cvi = cum(adv1 - dec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an indentation problem with each `exch ==` line.
The continuation of a statement must begin with one or several (different from multiple of 4) spaces.
You need each of those lines to be recognized as part of the `adv_ticker` or `dec_ticker`, so you need to add an extra space (5 blanks). This is explained under [Line wrapping](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html) in the [Pine Script 4 User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/index.html).

Also, `period` became `timeframe.period` in Pine v4.

I've changed your input a little to make the `Exchange` dropdown look cleaner.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

var EXCH0 = "NYSE"
var EXCH1 = "NASDAQ"
var EXCH2 = "AMEX"
var EXCH3 = "OTC"
var EXCH4 = "TSX"
var EXCH5 = "TSXV"
var EXCH6 = "ETFS"
var EXCH7 = "Total"
var EXCH8 = "CAD Total"

// exch = input(0, type = input.integer, minval=0, maxval=8, title="Exch: NYSE=0 NASDAQ=1 AMEX=2 OTC=3 TSX=4 TSXV=5 ETFS=6 Total=7 CAD Total=8")
exch = input(EXCH0, type = input.string, title="Exchange", options=[EXCH0,EXCH1,EXCH2,EXCH3,EXCH4,EXCH5,EXCH6,EXCH7,EXCH8])

var adv_ticker = 
     exch == EXCH8 ? "AVVX" : 
     exch == EXCH7 ? "AVVT" : 
     exch == EXCH6 ? "AVVE" : 
     exch == EXCH5 ? "AVVV" : 
     exch == EXCH4 ? "AVVS" : 
     exch == EXCH3 ? "AVVD" : 
     exch == EXCH2 ? "AVLU" : 
     exch == EXCH1 ? "AVVQ" : 
     "AVVN"

var dec_ticker = 
     exch == EXCH8 ? "DVCX" : 
     exch == EXCH7 ? "DVCT" : 
     exch == EXCH6 ? "DVCE" : 
     exch == EXCH5 ? "DVCV" : 
     exch == EXCH4 ? "DVCS" : 
     exch == EXCH3 ? "DVCD" : 
     exch == EXCH2 ? "DVCA" : 
     exch == EXCH1 ? "DVCQ" : 
     "DVCN"  

adv1 = security(adv_ticker, timeframe.period, close)
dec = security(dec_ticker, timeframe.period, close)
cvi = cum(adv1 - dec)

plot(na)
```

Comment: This is fantastic. And viola, it works now. Thank you so much.